# Why does my vim-7.3 compile fail to include clientserver?

Tags: vim, compiling

I am trying to compile vim-7.3 will all features enabled. I ran configure with

```
$ ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-gui --enable-cscope
$ make ; make install
```

When I check the version, it shows several features are still not installed.

> Huge version without GUI.  Features
>   included (+) or not (-):
>   +arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval **-browse** ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
>   **-clientserver -clipboard** +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
>   +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs 
>   -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path
>   **....**

Now according to [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+feature-list)

> N  *+browse*
>   N  *+clientserver*

It says

> Thus if a feature is marked with "N", it is included in the normal, big and huge versions of Vim.

`features.h` also says

> +huge                all possible features enabled.

According to the above mentioned two resources, `huge` means all features are enabled. Even if not all, then at least `+clientserver` and `+browse` has to be enabled in `huge` compilation mode.

But my experience says otherwise. Huge compilation fails to include browse and clientserver feature.

1. Why is it so? Is my understanding of the document is incorrect?
2. How to enable clientserver feature?
3. How to enable gui?
4. Is it possible to enable **all** features simply? I tired huge as `features.h` suggested it will enable all possible features, but it didn't work.

Thanks for your time.

## Edit: Problem solved!

Thanks to all of you guys for your priceless help.
I checked, `vim73/src/auto/config.log`, it was clear that lots of dependencies are missing. [Gert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2807/why-my-vim-7-3-compile-fails-to-include-clientserver/2822#2822) post gave an idea which packages are required. I used:

```
$ yum -yv install libXt.i686 libXt-devel.i686 \
libXpm.i686 libXpm-devel.i686 \
libX11.i686 libX11-common.noarch libX11-devel.i686 \
ghc-cairo-devel.i686  cairo.i686   \
libgnomeui-devel.i686 \
ncurses.i686 ncurses-devel.i686  ncurses-libs.i686 ncurses-static.i686 \
ghc-gtk-devel.i686 gtk+-devel.i686 \
gtk2.i686  gtk2-devel.i686 \
atk-devel.i686 atk.i686 \
libbonoboui.i686 libbonoboui-devel.i686
```

Some of the packages were already installed, others were not. After that:

```
$ ./configure --with-features=huge --enable-cscope --enable-gui=auto
$ make ; make install
```

Now my vim has all the packages associated with `huge`.

> Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-): 
>   +arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
>   **+clientserver** +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
>   +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
>   +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi
>   **...**

Thanks

Comment: It is possible you lack certain dependencies for those features.

Comment: @Gert: Thanks for the response. What could that be? Any idea?

Comment: whats the output of your logfiles? ./configure for example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this building Vim page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim), you'll need these dependencies on Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev \
   libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libbonoboui2-dev \
   libcairo2-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev
```

Run `configure` again.

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gnome2 --enable-cscope
```

I've tried and all seemed to be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

The test in feature.h is

```
#if (defined(WIN32) || defined(FEAT_XCLIPBOARD)) && defined(FEAT_EVAL)
# define FEAT_CLIENTSERVER
#endif
```

so you have to make sure that FEAT_XCLIPBOARD is enabled. This is done here:

```
#if defined(FEAT_NORMAL) && defined(FEAT_VISUAL) \
        && (defined(UNIX) || defined(VMS)) \
        && defined(WANT_X11) && defined(HAVE_X11)
# define FEAT_XCLIPBOARD
# ifndef FEAT_CLIPBOARD
#  define FEAT_CLIPBOARD
# endif
#endif
```

So it looks as if you miss some X11-devel package.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the output of `./configure` and at `config.log`.